# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when using a function inside another function in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, request

I'm extracting the original URL from twitter using NodeJS and I have the following functions

First I extract the tweet and save its body in a variable as follows

```
getTweets().then(tweets=>{
    let tweet = tweets[0].text;
    let tcoURL = extractURL(tweet); //this function extracts the t.co url from tweet using regex
    console.log(tcoURL)
    
    //but when I execute this following function, I'm getting unhandled promise error
    extractTransactionURL(tcoURL).then(url=>{
        console.log(url)
    })
})
```

The extractTransactionURL function is as follows, it takes in t.co url and returns the original url

```
const request = require('request')

function extractTransactionURL(url){

    let headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Please gimme back the original url from the tweet"
    }
  
    var options = {
      url, headers
    }
  
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            request.get(options, function (error, resp, body) {
                    if (!error && resp.statusCode==200) {
                        resolve(resp.request.uri.href);
                    }
                    else{
                        reject(error)
                    }
                }
            ), 250})
    }); 
}
```

Please help, any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full error

```
(node:4216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: null
(node:4216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4216) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely not happening because of nested functions, but because of `.then()`. An `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` happens when the promise fails, and you don't have code to handle the rejection. Here, you have only one argument for `.then()` which handles fulfilled promises, but you should add a second argument that is a callback for rejected promises (what happens when the promise fails and is unfulfilled).

Basically, what is happening is that in your `extractTransactionURL(url)` function, we end up calling `reject(error)` in the promise it returns. However, the `.then()` has no callback to handle the rejection and throws the warning.

Here is what you could do:

```
getTweets().then(tweets=>{
    let tweet = tweets[0].text;
    let tcoURL = extractURL(tweet); //this function extracts the t.co url from tweet using regex
    console.log(tcoURL)
    
    extractTransactionURL(tcoURL).then(url=>{
        console.log(url)
    }, err=>{
        // DO SOMETHING TO HANDLE UNFULFILLED PROMISE
    })
}, err=>{
    // DO SOMETHING TO HANDLE UNFULFILLED PROMISE
});
```

Comment: Hi, it fixed the unhandled promise error but It's printing ```null``` when I execute it. It is working if I use the extractTransactionURL function without all this stuff. Do you know how to fix that? Edit: It worked. my mistake. Thanks :)

Comment: I think this mostly depends on the other methods you're calling that likely causes an error or bad status code which I assume causes one of promises to call the rejection callback instead of the fulfillment callback. However, I don't know enough about your specific situation to say.